# Should Law.Se have separate tags for jurisdiction and subject matter?

Tags: discussion, tags, jurisdiction

The tag field for Stack Exchange currently does not discriminate between the types of tags. This feature works fine for most Stack Exchange sites as the subject matter is universal. However there are many questions everyday on Law.SE that are unanswerable due to the jurisdiction not being defined. Rather than require members to try and solicit a jurisdiction from the OP or to edit based on the question would it be better to have a tag field for jurisdiction and one for subject matter instead of one?

The jurisdiction would not have to be a specific jurisdiction. It could be something [common-law](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/common-law), [legal-principles](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal-principles), or [schools-of-law](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/schools-of-law) general, but would reduce the number of questions like:

> Is it legal for my landlord to evict me for wearing a blue shirt?
>
> Tags: [eviction](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eviction) [leases](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leases) [no-country](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/no-country) [no-state](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/no-state) [guess-where](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guess-where)

which are not answerable or useful. Instead we could for questions to look more like:

> Is it legal for my landlord to evict me for wearing a blue shirt?
>
> Subject Matter: [eviction](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eviction) [leases](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leases) [contracts](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contracts)
> Jurisdictions: [united-states](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states) [oklahoma](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oklahoma)

There would obviously be technical challenges to program this and retag 10,000 questions, but would the site be better off in the long run if two tag fields were the case?

Answer (score 3):

As an *option* I think that could be helpful.

However, I am not a fan of unnecessary nagging for jurisdictions.  That has been discussed extensively under [jurisdiction](/questions/tagged/jurisdiction).  (My preference: In the absence of a jurisdiction, Answerers may assume any jurisdiction they want.  And even if a jurisdiction *is* indicated by the Asker, a helpful answer may reference law in another jurisdiction.)

Answer (score 2):

Although I get the impression that the technical barriers may be insurmountable, I would *strongly* support this change.

A question may be interesting enough that I'll solicit the OP for a jurisdiction, but there are quite a lot of questions that are too borderline for me to even bother asking anymore. I suspect that I am not the only one who is declining to even attempt answering questions from people who don't provide that crucial piece of information.

Answer (score 0):

That would be an interesting feature request.

While tag categories might be nice for people with technical backgrounds, most users would have to be stepped through the difference between categories in a nontechnical way.