# United States FOIA versus United Kingdom FOIA

Tags: discussion, tags

We currently have a [foia](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/foia) tag, which appears to be scoped to be specifically about the Freedom of Information Act in the United States (as well as state-level variations therein).  There is, however, an identically named and similarly themed piece of legislation within the United Kingdom.  This raises a few interrelated questions of how we might best address this particular situation, as well as the more general problem of distinct jurisdictions using very similar terminology and legislation names.

Should we have jurisdiction-specific tags, such as [us-foia](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-foia) and [uk-foia](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uk-foia), instead?  Or broaden the description of [foia](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/foia)? Would a general purpose [freedom-of-information](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/freedom-of-information) be warranted?

Additionally, the tag description refers simply to the "federal law", which is not a term unique to the United States (this appears to happen with other tags, as well, including [federal-law](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/federal-law)).  So surely either the tag name or description needs adjustment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good catch: There is no reason for the description on [foia](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/foia) to restrict it so adamantly to the U.S. Federal Freedom of Information Act.  I just edited the tag description accordingly: It's applicable to any law in any jurisdiction that applies to a government entity's legal obligation to share information.

The [general problem of "subject" tags being applicable in multiple jurisdictions has been discussed extensively here](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/725/10).

Current practice is:

- Ask people to use [jurisdiction](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jurisdiction) tags when necessary to avoid ambiguity
- Encourage people to use [jurisdiction](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jurisdiction) tags when helpful to narrow the applicable scope of the question
- But even when tagged with a [jurisdiction](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jurisdiction) [to admit answers on the subject that address other jurisdictions](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/39/10).